# Laravel Resources Returning null

Tags: laravel, laravel-resource

Returning laravel resource is giving null but the database have files. here is my resource class

```
class UsersResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
    'u_id' => $this->user_id,
    'u_name' => $this->user_name,
    ];
    }
}
```

My route file is here

```
Route::get('test2', function(){
    $xyx=Users::find(1);
    return new UsersResource($xyx);
});
```

My response is here as follows

```
{"data":{"u_id":null,"u_name":null}}
```

thanks

Comment: Please share the users table structure. does it contain `user_id` or `user_name` columns?

Comment: it's `id` and `name` by default

Comment: @Alexandar Bishop thanks i got the hint from your comment.And it works

Answer (score 1):

It's because Users table doesn't contain user_id or user_name columns by default. It's `id` and `name` by default. So you should change the code like below.

```
class UsersResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */

    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
           'u_id' => $this->id,
           'u_name' => $this->name,
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Resource does just formatting your Eloquent Model.
Check out the querying result(in your case, `$xyx`) first.

```php
dd($xyx);
```

As mentioned by @Alexandr-Biship, you may try to access wrong field.